# Arbitrary intersection operation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Show that if $\mathscr R$ is nonempty, then $A \cup \bigcap \mathscr R = \bigcap \{A\cup X | X \in \mathscr R\}$.

**Solution**. First observe that for any $X \in \mathscr R$, $ \bigcap \mathscr R \subseteq X$. Hence $A \cup \bigcap \mathscr R \subseteq A \cap X$ for all $X \in \mathscr R$, and thus $A \cup \bigcap \mathscr R \subseteq \bigcap \{A\cup X | X \in \mathscr R\}$. 
Now take any $x \in \bigcap \{A\cup X | X \in \mathscr R\}$. So $x \in A \cup X$ for all $X \in \mathscr R$. If $x \in A$, the containment holds. Otherwise, if $x \not\in A$, we must have $x \in X$ for all $X \in \mathscr R$, that is, $x \in \bigcap \mathscr R$, and the equality follows.

**My proof**: 
$x \in A \cup \bigcap \mathscr R$ 
 $\Rightarrow$ $x \in A$ or $x \in \bigcap \mathscr R$ by definition of union
$\Rightarrow$ $x \in A$ or $(\forall X \in \mathscr R)(x \in X)$ by definition of arbitrary intersection 
$\Rightarrow$ $(\forall X \in \mathscr R)(x \in A \cup X)$ by definition of union 
$\Rightarrow$ $x \in \bigcap \{A\cup X | X \in \mathscr R\}$ by definition of arbitrary intersection
 Furthermore every step can be reversed.

My method differs from the solution. Is my proof also valid?

Comment: Looks good to me. One thing I see is that a naive student may not understand why it's important that $\mathscr{R}$ is nonempty. Your proof doesn't make it clear either. One of the reverse implications is no longer true if it is empty (ignoring the fact that the intersection is defined on nonempty sets)

Comment: @AlbertoTakase Thanks for checking. About your "One of the reverse implications is no longer true if ...", did you mean even if $\mathscr R$ is the empty set, the all(four) $\Rightarrow$ in my proof still valid and one would be invalid when the implications are reversed? I thought when $\mathscr R$ is the empty set then $\bigcap \mathscr R$ and $\bigcap \{A \cup X|X \in \mathscr R\}$ become no loger sets(my book describes it as class), so any further discourse can't be started because they are not defined in ZFC set theory. Then do you assume another axiom? I want to understand your saying.

Comment: Let $x$ be a set satisfying $(\forall X\in \mathscr{R})(x\in A\cup X)$. It can be proven that "$x\in A$ or $(\forall X\in \mathscr{R})(x\in X)$" when $\mathscr{R}$ is nonempty.

Comment: I was ignoring the fact that the intersection is not defined on the empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a negligable improvement

**My proof(edited by A.T.)**: 
$x \in A \cup \bigcap \mathscr R$ 
 $\Leftrightarrow$ $x \in A$ or $x \in \bigcap \mathscr R$ by definition of union
$\Leftrightarrow$ $x \in A$ or $(\forall X \in \mathscr R)(x \in X)$ by definition of <s>arbitrary</s> intersection 
$\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathscr{R}\ne\varnothing$ and $(\forall X \in \mathscr R)(x \in A \cup X)$ by definition of union 
$\Leftrightarrow$ $x \in \bigcap \{A\cup X | X \in \mathscr R\}$ by definition of <s>arbitrary</s> intersection